# For loop adding dicts in dicts without overwriting

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to write the code as simple as possible. And it's already creating nearly the dict I'm looking for. But the subdictionaries `{str(row[0]):`are sadly going to be overwritten. Now I'm looking for a way to store the first values of a line for each `Blue Item` in subdict without overwriting the values before it.

**Sample Data:**

```
header = ["title 01", "title 02", "title 03", "title 04", "title 05", "title 06", "title 07", "title 08"]

table = [
    "Blue Item 01",
    "221 4.055 8.452581582427 4.4838340356 8.679611220757502 5.55358892234839 9.09286848348221896 9.45332056441802",
    "36500 9.488 3.48463473994 9.0407483482094 3.7868682447595 2.8868694465 7.0846841221896 10.4532222485381913",
    "*863840* 4.48 3.48684556114014 8.48383792859 6.638658464 4.255483845575 98.8348251221896 6.453140463508968",
    "864 83.45 8.48383838 8.4216448838433569 0.278373887378 4.4886384384 48.48384396 9.11435133645320674",

    "Blue Item 02",
    "3450 254.525 0.716826 0.1119312 0.774307631256817 2.66236555555556 0.0927734375 75.106087857865277778",
    "*486* 68786.0855 0.581674826764762 0.079744514631212 0.731168630226715 2.98093827813281 75.09277875775 0.107678128890664",
    "864 7858.5805 843.5248380816 9.04838432127 3.48348384830 3.1868738734687 0.043834884375 4838.483843734",

    "Blue Item 03",
    "9600 2.528463 0.84684626 486846.4868312 48648.7743048648625486817 8464.66234868465556 48.0948684375 8648.486847778",
    "*1023* 8.486845 48684.584868762 4868.0797846481212 48648.7314868715 2.980486843281 4864.4868734375 48684.148648890664",
    "8453 25.4525 9.5448684816 48648.066353806612787 486.7095378308819 846697.186078614687 78640.0927786784375 786.1086831734"]
```

**Code:**

```
table_dict = {}
for i in table:
    global blue_item
    if i.startswith("Bl"):
        blue_item = str(i)
        # print(i)
    else:
        # print(i)
        row = i.split(" ")
        table_dict[blue_item] = {                # Blue Item
            str(header[0]): {str(row[0]): {       # title 01
                str(header[1]): float(row[1]),    # title 02
                str(header[2]): float(row[2]),    # title 03
                str(header[3]): float(row[3]),    # title 04
                str(header[4]): float(row[4]),    # title 05
                str(header[5]): float(row[5]),    # title 06
                str(header[6]): float(row[6]),    # title 07
                str(header[7]): float(row[7])}}}  # title 08

pprint(table_dict)
```

**Goal: (Only parts of the goal to get the idea)**

```
 'Blue Item 01': {'title 01': {'221': {'title 02': 4.055,
                                                         'title 03': 8.452581582427,
                                                         'title 04': 4.4838340356,
                                                         'title 05': 8.679611220757502,
                                                         'title 06': 4.24622875213704,
                                                         'title 07': 5.55358892234839,
                                                         'title 08': 9.45332056441802}
                                              {'36500': {'title 01': 9.488 ,
                                                         'title 02': 3.48463473994,
                                                         'title 03': 9.0407483482094,
                                                         'title 04': 3.7868682447595,
                                                         'title 05': 2.8868694465,
                                                         'title 06': 7.0846841221896,
                                                         'title 07': 7.0846841221896,
                                                         'title 08': 10.4532222485381913}
                                            {'*863840*': {'title 01': 4.48 ,
......

}},
```

Comment: Does the `title` number just below `Blue item` have the same numbers ?

Comment: I'm sorry fixed it was a writing mistake that title 01 repeated

Comment: Can you explain how the structure is built, maybe by extending the desired output for `Blue Item 2` ?

Comment: `title 01` number is unique for each Blue Item but probably repeats in the next blue item.

Comment: The structure is split by each `Blue Item` and by each first item in a row that's not starting with Blue.

Comment: The desired output structure isn't valid, does the dict below `'title 01'` is a list of dict ?

Comment: `Blue Item` dicts are dicts in `table_dict`

Comment: If you run the code I provided you see the structure and see that only the last row for each Blue Item is existing in a dict. Hope that helps

Comment: Just corrected the test code to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the overwriting of `table_dict[blue_item]` inside the `else` block. The solution below solves that problem.

```
table_dict = {}
blue_item = ''
for i in table:
    global blue_item
    if i.startswith("Bl"):
        blue_item= str(i)
        table_dict[blue_item] = {
            str(header[0]): {}
        }
        # print(i)
    else:
        # print(i)
        row = i.split(" ")
        table_dict[blue_item][str(header[0])][str(row[0])] = {
                str(header[1]): float(row[1]),
                str(header[2]): float(row[2]), 
                str(header[3]): float(row[3]),
                str(header[4]): float(row[4]),
                str(header[5]): float(row[5]),
                str(header[6]): float(row[6]),
                str(header[7]): float(row[7])}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I thought I can assign it like this but this didn't work `table_dict[blue_item] = str(header[0])
       table_dict[blue_item][str(header[0])] = {str(row[0]): {...` and I can see that you create the first dicts directly after if. Your approach solved it. Thanks a lot.